# Novice terminal , php, "-bash: export: not a valid identifier"

Tags: bash, cakephp, terminal, mamp, identifier

I'm a newbie web developer, and using OSX 10.9.4.

I'm trying to install MAMP, but there's an error shown in terminal every time I opened it:

```
-bash: export:`/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin:/Users/Admin/Library/cakephp-cakephp-74836f8/lib/Cake/Console:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin': not a valid identifier
```

I try to do another command line, but it has the same error:

```
Admin-MacBook-Pro::~ Admin$ ls -la
-bash: ls: No such file or directory

Admin-MacBook-Pro:~ Admin$ printenv | grep MAMP
-bash: grep: No such file or directory
-bash: printenv: No such file or directory

Admin-MacBook-Pro:~ Admin$
```

I don't know if I have missed any step. How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance,

phii

Comment: It sounds like you have two different questions here. Perhaps you should take the ls question to [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/). Additionally, for the MAMP installation, it would help to post the command you executed to cause the "not a valid identifier" error.

Comment: Sounds more like either your or the MAMP installer, in the process of installing it, blew away your PATH variable. Try resourcing your bash files i.e. `. ~/.bashrc ~/.bash_profile`. And as the above comment points out, you would likely get more help on another SE site, since this isn't a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if youre adding the colon or not.. but if you do this command in bash:

```
ls -la
```

it should give a list of directories. as for your export, you can edit your `.bashrc` and add the path that way, reboot your terminal and check if php is installed by doing:

```
printenv | grep MAMP
```